# aqtinstall trouble Installing Qt with QtWebview Module in a Windows Docker Container

Tags: windows, qt, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to install Qt 5.15.2  using **aqt** within a Windows **Docker** container. I'm in the process of setting up a CI/CD pipeline, and one of the requirements is to have Qt installed in the Windows Docker container. However, I specifically need the **QtWebview** module, along with some other modules.

I've tried specifying the QtWebview module using the command line during installation, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Even after installation, when I navigate to the installation directory, I can't locate the QtWebview module. Additionally, attempting to compile my code within the container also fails.

Here's the command I've been using for the installation:

```
aqt install-qt --outputdir c:\Qt --windows desktop 5.15.2 win64_mingw81 --modules all --archives qtbase qtmultimedia qtdeclarative qtsvg qtwebview
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

PS: here is the full docker container

```
# escape=`

# Use the latest Windows Image 20h2
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2
ENV VS160COMNTOOLS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools

WORKDIR C:\init

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# install choco (win package manager like apt-get)
RUN @"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"

RUN choco install mingw -y

RUN choco install ninja -y

# install cmake
RUN choco install cmake -y `
    && set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\

# install git    
RUN choco install git -y `
    && set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\

# Install Python and pip
RUN choco install python -y
RUN set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python39\Scripts

# Install aqt 
RUN pip install aqtinstall

# Install qt
RUN  aqt install-qt --outputdir c:\Qt windows desktop 5.15.2 win64_mingw81 --modules all --archives qtbase qtmultimedia qtdeclarative qtsvg qtwebview

# run.bat 
COPY run.bat .

# start run.bat when container started
CMD C:\init\docker\windows\run.bat
~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone reading this post. In fact, it is not possible to install this particular module for Qt for MingW version 5.15.2.  You must therefore either change version or change method